# MediaWiki API: Linked pages for a given page

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Using the MediaWiki API, is it possible to retrieve a list of page titles associated with a page of a given name via outlinks? For instance, assume that there is a page called "Cat" in my MediaWiki installation which has the contents

> Cats hate **dogs**, but love **mice**.

where links to to other pages are in bold. Is there an API call which would return a list of titles of the linked pages (i.e. "Dog" and "Mouse")?

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: My first idea was to scroll through the API help page that lists the API's actions and their respective parameters. The two "action=query" parameters that struck me were "list=allpages" and "list=alllinks" whose names at first suggested to me that they might return the linked pages or links for a given page, yet when these parameters are passed to the API, it expects namespaces rather than a page title. If the API doesn't support the functionality I need, then the emergency solution would be to get the contents of the given page and to obtain the outlinks by manual parsing.

Comment: Speaking of parsing... I just stumbled upon the "parse" action which at first glance seems to support the required functionality. I guess this is exactly where you wanted to point me by asking me your Socratic question :-)

Comment: No, not really. I was just reviewing your first question and was missing vital information. If you found a solution, don't forget to post it here and mark as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want prop=links, eg: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles=Dog

docs: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties#links_.2F_pl